# In-Amp Common Mode Rejection With Unbalanced Device Impedance

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I am using an instrumentation amplifier ([AD8220](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8220.pdf)) to interface a pH probe.  The pH probe produces a +/-414mV signal with large output impedance (>100MOhm). AD8220 has very low input bias current (~10pA) and low offset voltage (~500uV).

When I simulate with no pH probe impedance and a 1V common mode voltage, the output is as expected, with common mode totally removed.

[image]

However, when I add 100MOhm in series with my probe there is a considerable offset (~700mV), greater than the 10pA bias current can produce.  I expect input impedance of the in-amp is very large (>1TOhm) and fairly balanced.  Why is this offset produced?

[image]

Comment: First thing crossing my mind (your circumstances) was to use a JFET. I had no idea about the AD8220. But it's a JFET input opamp. So, I think you are playing in the right ballpark, anyway. I'll +1 the question, too. (I don't have an answer right now.)

Comment: Could you please share a link to the documentation of the pH probe? I'm not sure this should be a new question or an edit to this one but maybe there is a different/better way to model it.

Comment: The pH probe is Chinese made, and documentation is sparse: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2255799999624524.html -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this offset produced?

Because this LTSpice model is taking a much larger input current than the datasheet indicates:

[image]

LTSpice usually has good models for AD and LT devices. Strange. *Edit: new model, still large currents*

According to the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8220.pdf) these would be the currents around 80C or so.

Comment: Yes - this is the answer... I did not consider the model is incorrect.  Will create a ticket w/ ADI.

Comment: @Rherma I don't think so. Just looking at the datasheet right now. I think your problem is not seeing "source imbalance" in the datasheet or following that up with an LTspice simulation that is set up correctly.

Comment: @jonk I did see that in the datasheet, and when I simulate with 100Meg on both sides of the input the common mode voltage disappears.  However, surely the source impedance is in series with the device input impedance, which is several orders of magnitude larger.  I am missing something, could not find any other discussion of "source imbalance" in other technical documents.

Comment: Just informing that the above plot was obtained without the resistor (and the **offset** current is quite small, and almost identical to spec).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

The data looks like this:

[image]

I suspect that if you start a ticket, they may suggest something similar to try out. They really are pretty good at vetting their models.

Comment: Yes, this configuration produces the expected output with acceptable common mode rejection.  However, the input current to the in-amp is still unexpectedly high (almost 1nA).  This is producing a large voltage drop over the 50Meg device impedance (but balanced by the other 50Meg on the inverting input).  I must be missing something.

Comment: @Rherma At least it is now a different question both here and that you may present on a ticket to others. I'll have to look over the datasheet to have any chance to figure out this *new* issue. Also note that there are different grades specified in the datasheet. I don't know which grade is modeled here.

Comment: Six of one, half dozen of the other :) I am not so sure it is a different question, since in the case you provided, the device impedance is "balanced".  In reality, I am not so sure how to model the pH probe impedance.  Physical construction leads me to think most of the impedance is produced by the various membranes and liquid junctions in the probe which surely is just in series with the voltage output.  Whether this is an LTSpice question, or more fundamental about the operation of in-amps is to be answered.  Hopefully ADI apps engineers will shine some  much needed light on my question.

Comment: @Rherma The output is certainly no longer the one you show in the question. So the presentation of your facts has changed. But sure. Agreed. Definitely talk with them! And/or just buy one and set it up and see. That's what I often did before calling in an FAE. (And yeah... just looking... an nA does seem excessive to me.)

Comment: Yes, this does reduce the common mode voltage (but by a factor of the difference in gain - 5x).  Maybe this helps iron out questions regarding "source imbalance" and gain having an effect on the common mode rejection?  Unsure - but I do agree, testing on the real chip would help.  I do have some samples order now

Comment: @Rherma Best wishes on the results. I'm hoping it meets what you perceive from the datasheet and that LTspice needs its model fixed.